# Trying to display an array list in Struts 2 and get an error

Tags: struts2, arraylist

Here is my code and I get an error can anyone tell me what the reason could be ?

```
  <s:select label="Index" name="index" list="%{#{}}">
     <s:iterator value="#session.subscription_countries" var="slist">
         <s:property/>
    <s:if test='#slist=="CANADA" || #slist=="ALL"'>
    <s:optgroup label="Canada" list="%{#{'TSX':'TSX'}}" />
    </s:if>
    <s:if test='#slist=="UK" || #slist=="ALL"'>
    <s:optgroup label="United Kingdom" list="%{#{'FTSE100':'FTSE100'}}" />
    </s:if>
    <s:if test='#slist=="USA" || #slist=="ALL"'>
    <s:optgroup label="USA" list="%{#{'S&P500':'S&P500'}" />
    </s:if>
    <s:if test='#slist=="INDIA" || #slist=="ALL"'>
    <s:optgroup label="India" list="%{#{'NIFTY':'NIFTY','CNX100':'CNX100'}}" />
    </s:if>
     </s:iterator>

    </s:select>
```

Error

### Java backtrace for programmers:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression optGroupInternalListUiBean.parameters.list is undefined on line 36, column 8 in template/simple/optgroup.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:100)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:416)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1482)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1482)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209
```

Comment: what you trying to do? can you explain it

Comment: I am retrieving an array list from the session and adding the appropriate drop down element based on the content of the array list

Comment: Its an array list of String objects

Comment: not sure about this as never used it, but why `list="%{#{}}` is empty?

Comment: Dropdown contains items which are grouped under a label, I iterate through the list to determine which items to populate.

Comment: As error says, something is wrong with list on s:optgroup tags. Try to change S&P500 to S&amp;P500

Comment: If one action is handling this view why not move the logic to build your opt group into the action so you just need to iterate without all those if statements.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Struts 2.2 tried replacing the Struts optgroup tag with plain html and it works fine.

Comment: This one was a teaser. The problem was the missing brace for optgroup "USA"

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to get list from session and iterate it into  box, if i am right then u can try this.

" listValue="
Here 
1.list is the name of your list 
2.headerKey/headerValue - no necessary but if you add it then they will appear at the top of your select box
3. listKey :- it will become  on your page and is the class in the list and value is the variable, having value, in class.
4. listValue :- same as listKey

if listKey/listValue is string objects then write  instead of

i hope this will help
Thanks